# Deleting empty rows with a loop only deletes first empty row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently working on a script that is supposed to delete rows from a dataset, that are marked as 'done' or empty. I have a working loop, that deletes all done rows but only the first row of each set of empty rows.

I've found multiple solutions for this but all of those where incrementing `i` and thus needed to keep track of the number of deleted rows in order to match the correct row when deleting the next.

```
function sheetclear(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet");
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
    var firstrow = 5;
    var numrow = range.getNumRows()-firstrow;
    var values = sheet.getRange(firstrow,1,numrow+1,8).getValues();


    if(sheet.getRange("h3").getValue() == true){ //h3 acts as a trigger
        for (i = parseInt(numrow)-1; i >= 0; i--){
            var row = values[parseInt(i)]

            if(row[7] == "done" || (row[1] == "" && values[(parseInt(i)+1)][1] != "")){
                sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+firstrow))
            }
        }

        //Re-adding the deleted rows and formatting them
        sheet.insertRowsAfter(sheet.getLastRow(),100-sheet.getLastRow());
        sheet.getRange(firstrow,1,numrow+1,8).setBorder(false, true, false, true, true, false, "silver",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID)
        sheet.getRange("h3").setValue(false);
    }
}
```

I am an amateur at JavaScript so the (probably obvious) solution eludes me. I suspect it has something to do with the values getting checked once and not after every single iteration.

Could anyone here point me towards the right path?

Comment: I suspect it's to do with your `if` statement, your `||` operator may not function how you're expecting it to.

Comment: could you elaborate on that? I don't see what could be wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(row[7] == "done" || (row[1] == "" && values[(parseInt(i)+1)][1] != ""))
```

The above condition is evaluated to true when:

- The 7th column of a row has value 'done'
  OR
- The 1st column of a row is empty and 1st column of the next row is not empty

So, if you have multiple adjacent rows with empty values, neither conditions will be satisfied except for one row. hence, it will delete only one row.

Please remove the second part of the && condition and make it like:

```
if(row[7] == "done" || (row[1] == ""))
```

Comment: Yeah, with the rest of the script adding the missing rows this would work. But that's not what I was interested in - I wanted to just delete empty rows within the data range containing values. (every empty row before the last entry in the list)This is why I check the next row.

Comment: @Bartholomew let us assume the data range looks like this: row1:data, row2: data, row3:empty, row4:empty, row5:empty, row6:data, row7:done, row8:empty, row9:data. In this case we would like to see row3, row4, row5, row7 and row9 to be deleted right? If this understanding is not right please let me know.

Comment: assuming you meant row8 instead of row9 being deleted, yes.

Comment: My bad. Yes, I meant row3, row4, row5, row7, and row8 to be deleted. In that case the condition if(row[7] == "done" || (row[1] == "")) would work. if you want you can check for other column values for an empty string instead of just the one like:  if(row[7] == "done" || (row[1] == "" && row[2]=="" && row[3]=="")). You do not need to check the next row values while deciding on whether you have to delete the current row.  By adding this check: values[(parseInt(i)+1)][1] != "", you were essentially doing that.

Comment: I needed to check the next row to make sure that I just delete empty rows within my dataset and not in the whole sheet. So with your example, if there where a row10-row20 with no data, your solution would delete those too. I found a working and relatively simple way to solve this as I posted below.

Answer (score 0):

> You are looping backwards and compare rows values and rows as a
>   function of your counter variable - this makes the code confusing. You
>   end up erasing the wrong rows.

**I suggest you to modify your code in the following way:**

```
function sheetclear(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet");
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
    var firstrow = 1;
    var numrow = range.getNumRows();
    if(sheet.getRange("h3").getValue() == true){ //h3 acts as a trigger
        for (var i = numrow-1; i >0; i--){
            var rowValues=sheet.getRange(i,1,2,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
            if(rowValues[0][7] == "done" || rowValues[0][1] == "" && rowValues[1][1] != ""){
                sheet.deleteRow(i)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will erase all the rows where the cell in column B (array entry [1]) is empty, while the cell below it has a value. I hope, I understood it right that this is your desired functionality.

Also, please get rid of parseInt(), this is not necessary for your code.

Answer (score 0):

@ziganotschka
Thanks for the pointers. I didn't know that the loop doesn't check the status of the datasheet after deleting a row.

Your solution works. However, it seems to be a much slower function. Another way I found, is to just add a function call into my loop so it goes through the sheet as often as needed.

I set for simply limiting the range to end at the last cell containing written data (by using a formula in the sheet) and simplifying the function as fiveelements pointed out in his first answer.

It looks something like this:

```
function sheetclear(){ 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet");

  var fr = 5;
  var lr = sheet.getRange("i3").getValue() //this is where I calculate the last occupied cell

  var range = sheet.getRange(fr,1,lr,8)
  var val = range.getValues()


  if(sheet.getRange("h3").getValue() == true){
    for (var i = lr; i>=fr; i--){
      if(val[i-fr][1] == "" || val[i-fr][7] == "done"){
        sheet.deleteRow(i)
      }
   }

//Re-adding the deleted rows and formating them
sheet.insertRowsAfter(sheet.getLastRow(),100-sheet.getLastRow());
sheet.getRange(fr,1,sheet.getLastRow(),8).setBorder(false, true, false, true, true, false, "silver",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID)
sheet.getRange("h3").setValue(false);

  }
}
```